# ag-grid cellRendererFramework not work in angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, cellrenderer

I'm trying to add a simple component in ag-grid table cell . I flow the instructions in aggrid website but it dos'nt render the component . here is my code :

```
  columnDefs = [
{ headerName: "Name", field: "name" ,width: 400},
{ headerName: "GoodsFinalCode", field: "goodsFinalCode" ,width:  200},
{ headerName: "operation", field: "operation" ,cellRendererFramework: OperationComponent, width: 450} 
];


rowData  = [ {
      name : 'b',
      goodsFinalCode :6,
 }
 ]
```

the gridoptiopns is :

```
  this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
  rowData: this.rowData,
  columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
  context: {
      componentParent: this
  },
  enableColResize: true
```

};

and the componet is :

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
        selector: 'app-operation',
        templateUrl: './operation.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./operation.component.scss']
        })

     export class OperationComponent  {


     private params: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
   }
   }
```

in operation html I just have a button. but nothing appear in aggrid cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The component you are using as the cell renderer should implement the ICellRendererAngularComp given from ag-grid.

operation.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-operation',
  templateUrl: './operation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./operation.component.css']
})
export class OperationComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  private params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

Then you must tell aggrid to use this operation component as a custom component. It is done by providing them in the AgGridModule.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OperationComponent } from './grid/options-cell-renderer/options-cell-renderer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OperationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      OperationComponent
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```